# Inserting duplicate value in indexeddb

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, indexeddb

When i insert on my database , it inserting same data twice.

**Table Create**

```
var oOptions = {
    keyPath: account.primaryKey,
    autoIncrement: true
};
var oStore = dbHandle.createObjectStore(account.tableName, oOptions);

var oIxOptions = {
    unique: false
};
account.fields.forEach(function(item) {
    oStore.createIndex(item + "Index", item, oIxOptions);
});
```

**Insert**

```
var defered = $q.defer();
try {
    var objectStore = config.database.transaction(tableName, "readwrite").objectStore(tableName);
    var result = objectStore.add(entity);
    result.onerror = function(e) {
        defered.reject("Can't insert into account");
        throw e;
    }
    result.onsuccess = function(e) {
        defered.resolve();
    }
} catch (e) {
    defered.reject("Can't insert into account");
    throw e;
}
return defered.promise;
```

**Retrive**

```
var defered = $q.defer();
try {
    var req = $window.indexedDB.open(config.databaseName, 1.0);
    req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
        config.database = evt.target.result;
        var transaction = config.database.transaction(account.tableName, IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY);
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(account.tableName);
        var tmpData = [];
        objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
            var cursor = event.target.result;
            if (!cursor) {
                defered.resolve(tmpData);
                return;
            }
            tmpData.push(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
        };
    }
} catch (e) {
    defered.reject("Can't pull from account");
    throw e;
}
return defered.promise;
```

Any suggestion ??

Comment: Is your insert method being called twice, or is it just inserting twice?  What triggers the call to the insert method?

Comment: this isn't related to the double insertion, but...
your using try/catch blocks wrapped in promises?

Comment: @tpie yes, shouldn't i use try ctach during promise ??

Comment: The promise allows that code block to run asynchronously, but try/catch is distinctly synchronous and blocking. If a request hangs in your try block your app will hang.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be less of a problem with indexedDB and more a problem with your use of try/catch and promises. Have you tested without try/catch and without promises? What is your rationale for using promises here? Consider that you don't need try/catch and you don't need promises to perform these simple tasks.

Comment: i was testing it on IE .. in Ionic IE trigger event twice for ng-click. After filtering the number of trigger i solved the problem.